# stopping strapi to then run a node command does nothing. What do i have to do to find out, where the error is?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mern

[image]

I have the following error :

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag \`--unhandled-rejections=strict\`
```

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, declare new object doesn't need `await`, so change your declare new user to `const user = new User(your_object_here)`

And what you mean in catch() then you throw error and catch again. Change you code to this and try again

```
try{
  // logic here
  res.send('ok')
}catch(error) {
  console.log('that did not go well');
  res.status(500).send('fail')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because you are trying to throw an error inside a `catch` bloc. [(documentation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)

If you really need to throw an error you must put another `try` / `catch` inside your `catch` block. But you should consider removing the `throw` and only print the error inside the catch and send a `500` [error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) .

```js
try {
  await user.save()
  res.send("ok");
} catch (Error e) {
  console.log(e);
  res.status(500).send('ko');
}
```